# How do I list all files and directories in a directory in Julia?

Tags: directory, julia

In Python, I could use:

```
from os import listdir
os.listdir()
```

In Julia, how can I list everything inside a given directory?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
readdir()
```

This lists all files and in a current directory folder as `Vector{String}`

Of course you can provide directory name:

```
readdir("dir/name")
```

On Windows a useful practice is `raw` `String` macro:

```
readdir(raw"c:\temp")
```

If you want to see what is in subdirectories use `walkdir`:

```
items = [item for item in walkdir("some/path")]
```

This walks through whole directory tree and returns a `Vector` of 3-element tuples where first element is directory, second list of it subdirectories and the third the list of files in a directory.

Comment: walkdir is the julia equivalent of python os.walk() it seems